# How to calculate the Intraclass correlation (ICC) in R?

Tags: r, correlation, mixed-models, longitudinal

I have a dataset that is in a long format with 200 variables, 94 subjects, and each subject has anywhere from 1 to 3 measurements for each variable.

Eg:

```
ID measurement var1 var2 . . .
1  1           2    6
1  2           3    8 
1  3           6    12
2  1           3    9
2  2           4    4
2  3           5    3 
3  1           1    11
3  2           1    4
.  .           .    .
.  .           .    .
.  .           .    .
```

However, some variables have missing values for one of three measurements. It was suggested to me that before imputing missing values with the mean for the subject, I should use a repeated measures ANOVA or mixed model in order to confirm the repeatability of measurements.

The first thing I found to calculate the ICC was the ICC() function from the psych package. However, from what I can tell this requires that the data have one row per subject and one column per measurement, which would be further complicated by the fact that I have 200 variables I need to calculate the ICC for individually. I did go ahead and calculate the ICC for a single variable, and obtained this output:

```
Intraclass correlation coefficients 
                         type  ICC   F df1 df2             p lower bound upper bound
Single_raters_absolute   ICC1 0.38 2.8  93 188 0.00000000067        0.27        0.49
Single_random_raters     ICC2 0.38 2.8  93 186 0.00000000068        0.27        0.49
Single_fixed_raters      ICC3 0.38 2.8  93 186 0.00000000068        0.27        0.49
Average_raters_absolute ICC1k 0.65 2.8  93 188 0.00000000067        0.53        0.74
Average_random_raters   ICC2k 0.65 2.8  93 186 0.00000000068        0.53        0.74
Average_fixed_raters    ICC3k 0.65 2.8  93 186 0.00000000068        0.53        0.74

 Number of subjects = 94     Number of Judges =  3
```

Next, I tried to calculate the ICC using a mixed model. Using this code:

```
m1 <- lme(var1 ~ measurement, random=~1|ID, data=mydata, na.action=na.omit)
summary(m1)
```

The output looks like this:

```
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
 Data: mydata
        AIC       BIC   logLik
  -1917.113 -1902.948 962.5564

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | ORIGINAL_ID
        (Intercept)    Residual
StdDev: 0.003568426 0.004550419

Fixed effects: var1 ~ measurement
                          Value    Std.Error  DF  t-value p-value
(Intercept)         0.003998953 0.0008388997 162 4.766902  0.0000
measurement         0.000473053 0.0003593452 162 1.316429  0.1899
 Correlation: 
                    (Intr)
measurement         -0.83 

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
        Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
-3.35050264 -0.30417725 -0.03383329  0.25106803 12.15267443 

Number of Observations: 257
Number of Groups: 94
```

Is this the correct model to use to assess ICC? It is not clear to me what the correlation (Intr) is measuring, and it is different from the ICC obtained using ICC().

This is my first time calculating and using intraclass correlation, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: (0.003568426)^2/((0.003568426)^2 + (0.004550419)^2) would give you the ICC from the mixed model. ICC is the percentage of variance explained at the cluster-level of interest.

Comment: Are you trying to get the ICC across all variables for the 3 measurements per variable per individual?

Comment: I am trying to get an ICC for each variable independently. So I will end up having to write some sort of loop to repeat the process for each variable, and will end up with a number of ICC equal to the number of variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a mock dataset...

```
set.seed(42)  
n <- 6
dat <- data.frame(id=rep(1:n, 2), 
                  group= as.factor(rep(LETTERS[1:2], n/2)),
                  V1 = rnorm(n),
                  V2 = runif(n*2, min=0, max=100), 
                  V3 = runif(n*2, min=0, max=100),
                  V4 = runif(n*2, min=0, max=100),
                  V5 = runif(n*2, min=0, max=100))
```

Loading some libraries...

```
library(lme4)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
# Add list of variable names to the vector below...
var_list <- c("V1","V2","V3","V4","V5")
```

map_dfr() is from the purrr library. I use lme4::VarCorr() to get the variances at each level.

```
map_dfr(var_list,
                  function(x){
                    formula_mlm = as.formula(paste0(x,"~ group + (1|id)"));
                    model_fit = lmer(formula_mlm,data=dat);
                    re_variances = VarCorr(model_fit,comp="Variance") %>% 
                      data.frame() %>% 
                      dplyr::mutate(variable = x);
                    return(re_variances)
                  }) %>% 
  dplyr::select(variable,grp,vcov) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from="grp",values_from="vcov") %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(icc = id/(id+Residual))
```